# CK editor5 React - Add custom button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

I have implemented react CK editor using the tutorial https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html

The code is as follows.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( 
            <div className = "App">                
            <h2> Using CKEditor 5 build in React < /h2> 
            <
            CKEditor editor = {
                ClassicEditor
            }
            data = "<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
            onInit = {
                editor => {
                    // You can store the "editor" and use when it's needed.
                    console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor);
                }
            }
            onChange = {
                (event, editor) => {
                    const data = editor.getData();
                    console.log({
                        event,
                        editor,
                        data
                    });
                }
            }
            />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Now i need to add a custom button to the toolbar which when clicked a function needs to be called.

I have seen posts on adding new plugins but i am not sure on how to implement this in the react way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a plugin that will register a new button. Then you can load your plugin to the editor. I will leave you some links to the documentation that should help you:

- [How to create a custom plugin?](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/quick-start.html#creating-a-simple-plugin)
- [How to make a custom button?](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/quick-start.html#step-3-registering-a-button)
- [How to add a plugin to the editor build?](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installing-plugins.html#adding-a-plugin-to-a-build)
- [Why cannot I add a plugin to existing build?](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1047)
- [How to integrate CKEditor 5 from source with React?](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html#integrating-ckeditor-5-from-source)